# Feeding a hidden tensor in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, autoencoder

I have an Some `autoencoder`. The model is not important now. Suppose that this model takes as input some image and output the reconstructed image. After training, I would like to see the effect of one tensor on the output. In addition, images are being fed into the `autoencoder` through a `FIFOQueue`. Therefore, when running the following peace of code:

```
reconstructed_image = sess.run([deconv_image], feed_dict={mu:my_vector})
```

where `deconv_image` is the output `tensor` of the model and `mu` is a hidden tensor inside the model; will automatically feed the model with an image from the `Queue`.

My question is: would the value inside `mu` be replaced by whatever should come from the input image, or, it takes the vector that I fed using the `feed_dict` argument.

Any help is much appreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When running the final tensor, that is, evaluating the last tensor of a graph, it will run all tensors which it depends on. So if we have `y3` operation which depends on `y2` and `y2` depends on `y1`, then, running the final tensor in the graph will cause `y1` to be run first, then `y2` is evaluated after it gets its input from `y1` and finally, the output of `y2` will feed into `y3`. This graph could be as follows: `y1 -> y2 -> y3`

On the other hand, I can run (evaluate) `y3` by feeding its inputs directly using the `feed_dict` argument. In this case, `y2` and `y1` are evaluated.

Ex:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

x = np.array([1.0, 2.0, 3.0])

x_var = tf.Variable(x, dtype=tf.float32)

y1 = tf.square(x_var)
y2 = tf.subtract(y1, tf.constant(1.0))

init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init_op)

    print(sess.run(y2)) # Output: [ 0.  3.  8.]
    print(sess.run(y2, feed_dict={y1: [1.0, 1.0, 1.0]}))# Output: [ 0.  0.  0.]
```